# Manipulate css style of a class depending on other class css style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using navigation drawer of Framework7 plugin on my hybrid app. The drawer can be open/close using the button as well as using swipe/slide left/right.

Now when the navigation drawer was open, the class `<div class="panel panel-left panel-reveal">` added another class which is `active` class. 
So when opened: `<div class="panel panel-left panel-reveal active ">`
when closed: `<div class="panel panel-left panel-reveal>`

Based on that event, is it possible to add style to other class?
Example is this class: `<div class="views">` to `<div class="views" style="opacity: 0.5">`

**What to accomplish:** When the drawer is open, the class `view` will add style, when drawer is close remove the `view` class style.

Is it possible to catch that event and accomplish what I would like to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Sorry for the delay, so below is the sample code to add a css class to a div only on hover event. I have done this using html and css only. (No DOM manipulation).

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            a.ex1:hover{color: red;}
            a.ex2:hover, a.ex2:active {font-size: 150%;}
            a.ex3:hover, a.ex3:active {background: red;}
            a.ex4:hover, a.ex4:active {font-family: monospace;}
            a.ex5:visited, a.ex5:link {text-decoration: none;}
            a.ex5:hover, a.ex5:active {text-decoration: underline;}
            .open-close{ display: none;}
            a.ex6:hover .open-close{display: block;}  
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
            <p>
                <a class = "ex1" href="#"> This link changes color </a>
            </p>
            <p>
                <a class = "ex2" href="#"> This link changes font-size </a>
            </p>
            <p>
                <a class = "ex3" href="#"> This link changes background-color </a>
            </p>
            <p>
                <a class = "ex4" href="#"> This link changes font-family </a>
            </p>
            <p>
                <a class = "ex5" href="#"> This link changes text-decoration </a>
            </p>
            <p>
                <a class = "ex6" href="#"> 
                    <div>This link displays another div by detecting change in class</div> 
                    <div class="open-close">
                        Here you can add your content to hide/show/modify elements based on the classes
                    </div>
                </a>
            </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

> NOTE - Just remember to use the appropriate CSS selector based on your HTML structure.
>
> Hope this helps. Let me know if you have any questions. Happy to help.

Comment: Pretty close of what I need, But in my case I need to get the event on the `<div class="panel">` When it added a class `active`, it should add a style as well to `<div class="views">` The class panel could add active class when button clicks and when the drawer swipes. I would like to look for the function in framework7 plugin but its hard to find.

Comment: @c.k . Hi yes it is possible, but i would like to see your html structure so that i can show you the appropriate css selector. If you dont mind.

Answer (score 0):

> Hi Yes it is Possible. Using HTML and Javascript itself. You can also achieve this using JQUERY DOM manipulation. Let me know which one would you want to know.

Comment: Any, but I prefer which is better.

Answer (score 0):

> I have modified your HTML a little

```
<div class="panel-overlay"></div>
            <div class="panel panel-left panel-reveal">Just to see if his appears in green on fire of a single common event</div>  <!---it adds "active class" e.g. <div class="panel panel-left panel-reveal active"> -->
            <div class="views"> Just to see if this appears in red on fire of a single common event<!--this should toggle change background, i mean add background color when  class panel has active class then remove the bgcolor when active class remove (vise versa) -->
                <div class="view view-main" data-page="home">
                  <div class="pages">
                     <div data-page="home" class="page navbar-fixed">
                        <div class="navbar">
                           <div class="navbar-inner">
                              <div class="left">
                                 <button onclick="myFunction()" type="button" class="open-panel fa fa-bars button-nav"> I am button 1</button>
                              </div>
                              <div class="center" style="left: -6.5px;"></div>
                              <div class="right">
                                 <button type="button" id="refresh" class="button-nav"> <i class="el el-refresh"></i> I am button 2</button>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="page-content">
                           <div class="content-block"> content here... </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
```

> Just add this JavaScript function and you will be good to go.

```
function myFunction(){
            $(".panel-reveal").addClass("active");
            if($(".panel-reveal").hasClass("active")) {
                $(".views").addClass("change")
            }
        }
```

> CSS will be

```
.active{
               background-color: green !important;
            }
            .change{
                background-color: red !important;
            }
```

> I hope this helped.